# How to write a script to copy from a windows share (\\....\...) to a certain location in docker

Tags: powershell, batch-file, docker

How to write a script to copy from a windows share (\.......) to a certain location in docker.

I have tried the following to find the latest sub-folder in windows share.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "\\....\.." /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (
SET a=%%i
GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof
:found
echo Most recent sub folder: %a%
```

Could Someone help me out with the script, as I am still learning?

TIA

Comment: What does this have to do with linux and bash?

Comment: @123 This is my first post, didn't knew tags has to be appropriate.

Comment: Do you expect the answer to be appropriate?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna Hope you would give me that appropriate answer.

Comment: @123, corrected the tags for you. Though it has nothing to do with docker, but i have still left the docker tag as it is